# PHP - Convert Image URL to SQL BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, binary, blob

I am programming with **PHP** and using **XAMPP** for **Apache** and **MySQL**.

I have searched and tried for two days a way to convert an image URL to a binary variable. After this process I try to insert it as a BLOB in a SQL database table.

I have tried several approaches (not included below) such as **base64()**, **file_get_contents()**, **save the image file** or even **cURL**...

Here's a picture of the **SQL database table structure**:[image]

and here's the "mind blowing psychedelic" **PHP** code:

```
<?php 
    // APPROACH #1
    $blob = file_get_contents('http://www.domainname.com/random/page/IMAGE.png');

    // APPROACH #2
    $bin = base64_encode($blob);

    // INSERT INTO QUERY
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO imagezzz (id_link, imagez) VALUES (?,?)");

    // APPROACH #1
    $stmt->bind_param("ib", $number, $blob);

    // APPROACH #2
    $stmt->bind_param("ib", $number, $bin);

    $stmt->execute();
?>
```

When the query is executed it throws **no error**. In fact the INSERT query is performed and a **new table line is added**. The first and second field (**id**[int] and **id_link**[int]) haves data but the the third field (**imagez** [BLOB]) is empty.

**I have performed a SQL INSERT QUERY inside phpMyAdmin (by uploading a local image) and it works fine...**

Comment: Do not use `addslashes` arbitrarily like this. It's a nearly useless function that's almost always inappropriate for the job at hand, *especially* SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get the file with `file_get_contents`, this ought to work:

```
$blob = file_get_contents('http://www.domainname.com/random/page/IMAGE.png');
print "Image is " . strlen($blob) . " bytes long\n";
$bin  = base64_encode($blob);
$estimate = round(strlen($blob)/0.75);
print "Blob is " . strlen($bin) . " bytes long (expecting about {$estimate}\n";
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO imagezzz (id_link, imagez) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->execute([ $number, $bin ]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time! I really mean it!
Unfortunately the blob insert still doesn't work. It creates a row with data except on the blob(imagez) field. Maybe the problem is from XAMPP, PHPMyAdmin or MySQL... I will search for some clue... Thanks anyways! 

Comment: @Grinnex. You may want to consider changing your Blob Field to a LongBlob if you're not receiving any INSERT Errors.